# Find lowest score and then a corresponding name with parallel arrays

Tags: arrays, indexing, parallel-processing, minimum

First off, sorry if this is a beginner question, but I am struggling to retrieve a corresponding person's name from a hardcoded array after finding the lowest test score from a parallel array. The assignment gave me the two arrays to use. I'm not sure on how to go about retrieving the index of the name. Here is what I have so far.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Lab0 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = {"Joey","Lisa","Karen","Mark","Christopher"};
        double[] scores = {78.5, 97.0, 42.5, 86.5, 42.5}; 


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
        "The lowest score is " + getMinValue(scores)
        );
    }

    public static double getMinValue(double[] scores){  
        double minValue = scores[0];  
        for(int i=1;i<scores.length;i++){  
        if(scores[i] < minValue){  
          minValue = scores[i];  
        }  
     }  
    return minValue; 
  } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean that:

String[] names = {"Joey","Lisa","Karen","Mark","Christopher"};
double[] scores = {78.5, 97.0, 42.5, 86.5, 42.5};

stands for Joey score is 78.5, Lisa is 97.0 and so on, you just need to realize that the same index accesses the correct information on both arrays. 
 
That is, 
 
scores[2] = 42.5 
names[2] = "Karen"

The index **i** that you are calculating in your *codegetMinValue(double[] scores)* function is the same one you need to get the corresponding name in the names array (names[i])).
I am assuming this is a school asignment since I would never organize data like this and I am sure doing the rest yourself will be very educative so I will let you think how to rewrite your code to store the index and the min value at the same time. There are several ways. You should also think what to do when the arrays are null. Did the assignment ask you to return the minimum and one name or the list of names if there are several people with the same minimum score? The way you are doing it you will only get one name which I supposed it is not what the assigment would want.